# Swagger: Combine Path and Query Parameters in Same REST Operation

Tags: swagger

Can you use both a path parameter and a query parameter in Swagger 2.0 or 3.0? For example, given the following base URL and path parameter:

```
/api.example.com/{path}
```

is it possible to add a query parameter, as in:

```
/api.example.com/{path}?<query_param>=<query_value>
```

My use case is the DELETE operation: `{path}` refers to an object ID to be deleted, and I'd like to add a flag so the requester can specify whether to try and force delete an object that ordinarily would not be deletable (think deleting a non-empty directory in Linux with `rm -f`). The URLs would then look like:

```
/api.example.com/{objectID123}                     (regular delete; will fail if object is non-empty)

/api.example.com/{objectID123}?forceDelete=True    (force delete)
```

I know I can specify both the object ID and the forceDelete flag as query parameters, but that would mean rewriting the DELETE operation as based solely on query parameters, while the other operations are all based on path parameters; I was hoping to keep everything consistent.

I read the documentation, but didn't find this question addressed explicitly. Note that I'm open to another way to handle the DELETE operation if there are best practices I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have different parameter types in the same operation.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
...
paths:
  /api.example.com/{objectID}:
    delete:
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: objectID
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
        - in: query
          name: forceDelete
          schema:
            type: boolean
            default: false
```

Comment: OP here: thanks! I'll give that a try and mark your answer as accepted once I verify that it works.